# Groovy concatenate ID and description in existing description tag

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying in Groovy to save a Hash table with the ID and Description of the xml, but cant make my work code to get the ID in the deeper level, right now i can only map correctly the Description.

Code

```
    import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message
    import java.util.HashMap
    import java.io.*
    import groovy.xml.*
    
      def body = message.getBody(java.io.Reader)
      HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
      def Root = new XmlSlurper().parse(body)
    
      Root.ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item.item.ExternalReqLineItems.item.each {
            try {
hmap.put(it.ItemDescription.text().toString(),it.LineExtrinsics.Extrinsics.Extrinsic.@InternalID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            //put relevant exception handling here
            }
      }
```

the XML:

```
<urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partition="" variant="">
    <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 1</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 1</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000083</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 2</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 2</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000084</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>     
    </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
</urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest>
```

What should be the right way to get the value from Extrinsic with name InternalID?

Expected Samples are:

7000083-TEST DESCRIPTION 1

7000084-TEST DESCRIPTION 2

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def data = '''\
<urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest xmlns:urn="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vrealm_1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" partition="" variant="">
    <urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 1</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 1</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000083</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>
        <urn:item>
            <urn:Name>Line 2</urn:Name>
            <urn:Operation>NEW</urn:Operation>
            <urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
                <urn:item>
                    <urn:ExternalLineNumber>2</urn:ExternalLineNumber>
                    <urn:ItemDescription>TEST DESCRIPTION 2</urn:ItemDescription>
                    <urn:Quantity>1.00</urn:Quantity>
                    <urn:LineExtrinsics>
                        <Extrinsics>
                            <Extrinsic name="InternalID">7000084</Extrinsic>
                        </Extrinsics>
                    </urn:LineExtrinsics>
                </urn:item>
            </urn:ExternalReqLineItems>
        </urn:item>     
    </urn:ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item>
</urn:ExternalReqForApprovalImportRequest>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)

// items is a Map<String, String> 
def items = xml.ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item.item.findAll { node -> 
  node.ExternalReqLineItems.item.LineExtrinsics.Extrinsics.Extrinsic.@name == "InternalID"
}.collectEntries { node -> 
  node.ExternalReqLineItems.item.with { 
    [LineExtrinsics.Extrinsics.Extrinsic.text(), ItemDescription.text()]
  }
}

println items
```

when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
[7000083:TEST DESCRIPTION 1, 7000084:TEST DESCRIPTION 2]
```

the [`findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) will iterate through the items and find all item nodes where the extrinsic name equals "InternalID". For those nodes, [`collectEntries`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) will transform the list (of item nodes) into a map where the keys are the `7000084` strings and the values are the `ItemDescription` strings.

If you want the concatenated strings as a result instead of a map, you can do this instead:

```
def items = xml.ExternalReqForApprovalInput_Item.item.findAll { node -> 
  node.ExternalReqLineItems.item.LineExtrinsics.Extrinsics.Extrinsic.@name == "InternalID"
}.collect { node -> 
  node.ExternalReqLineItems.item.with { 
    "${LineExtrinsics.Extrinsics.Extrinsic.text()}-${ItemDescription.text()}"
  }
}

println items
```

(note that we are now using [`collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) instead of `collectEntries`. `collect` returns a list of values)

which, when run, will print:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy                                                                                          
[7000083-TEST DESCRIPTION 1, 7000084-TEST DESCRIPTION 2]
```

where `items` is now a `List<String>` with the keys and values joined by hyphens `-`.